# Elixir: Variable undefined during AST expansion

Tags: macros, elixir, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a module like this, `ast1` and `ast2` look the same, but I get an error with `rest undefined` in second one. Can someone explain the problem?

```ex
defmodule PacketDef do
  pk_def = {:pk_name, [
    {:unk_int1, :int},
    {:unk_int2, :int},
  ]}

  {pkn, field_defs} = pk_def

  field_decs = Enum.map(field_defs, fn
    ({var_name, var_type}) when var_type in [:int] ->
        rest = Macro.var(:rest, __MODULE__)

        dec_name = String.to_atom("decode_#{var_type}")
        xvar_name = Macro.var(var_name, __MODULE__)
        quote do
            {:ok, unquote(xvar_name), unquote(rest)} = unquote(dec_name)(unquote(rest))
        end
    (_field_def) ->
        nil
  end)

  ast1 = quote do
      def decode(unquote(pkn), rest) do
        {:ok, unk_int1, rest} = decode_int(rest)
        {:ok, unk_int2, rest} = decode_int(rest)
        {:ok, rest}
      end
  end
  ast2 = quote do
      def decode(unquote(pkn), rest) do
        unquote_splicing(field_decs)        
        {:ok, rest}
      end
  end

  IO.puts("ast1")
  IO.inspect(ast1, width: 100)
  IO.puts("ast2")
  IO.inspect(ast2, width: 100)

  def decode(unquote(pkn), rest) do
    {:ok, unk_int1, rest} = decode_int(rest)
    {:ok, unk_int2, rest} = decode_int(rest)
    {:ok, rest}
  end

  # why get error *rest* here
  def decode(unquote(pkn), rest) do
    unquote_splicing(field_decs)        
    {:ok, rest}
  end

  def decode_int(<<b::32-little, rest::binary>>) do
    {:ok, b, rest}
  end
end
```

**update**

- What I want to do is, given `pk_def` generated `decode` function like in `ast1`, but with `fields decode` is generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the function definition not header, specifically the line:

```
unquote_splicing(field_decs)
```

If you remove this line, the code will work. The reason is that when the `field_decs` AST is expanded using `unquote_splicing`, it makes a sub-call trying to unquote `rest` variable which fails. Fixing how your AST gets evaluated will fix this as well.

---

<sup>*This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here but when dealing with language extension and custom DSLs, you should break it down into multiple smaller and composable [Macros](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html) (with the majority of functionality implemented in private functions) and should also take good care of macro hygiene. That will substantially reduce your code complexity and make it easier to deal with code expansion in general, since you won't have to deal with ASTs directly.*</sup>

Comment: I actually want to ask for *Y* here because I want to know more about macro/AST expansion other than solve *X* which may change a lot. I also know the problem is on  `unquote_splicing` but dont get what is wrong here.  *Fixing how your AST gets evaluated will fix this as well* < could you give some hint?

Comment: Can you update your question to explain (in detail) what you are trying to do? Since I can't figure that out, I can't tell you what to fix in your AST.